# Displaying SVG elements properly on IOS

Tags: html, css, ios, svg, rounded-corners

```css
svg {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.0725 );
}
rect {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  x: 2.5rem;
  y: 2.5rem;
  fill: aqua;
  rx: 1rem;
  ry: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect />
</svg>
```

In the snippet above the `rx` and `ry` properties are ignored in safari on ios14 ( on iphone atleast ) rendering a blue square *without* rounded corners:

[image]

I’ve tried including the `rx` and `ry` properties directly in the HTML but to the same effect on IOS:

*( it doesn't work either :/ )*:

```css
svg {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: rgba( 0,0,0,0.0725 );
}
rect {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  x: 2.5rem;
  y: 2.5rem;
  fill: aqua;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect rx='1rem' ry='1rem' />
</svg>
```

**Is this a glitch in IOS that `rx` and `ry` properties are ignored on SVG elements? If so are there any other known SVG properties affected by this issue and are there any workarounds?**

Comment: I think safari requires such things to be attributes rather than CSS properties.

Comment: @RobertLongson *Which* attributes and properties though? What's strange is Safari takes the `fill`, `x`, `y`, and who knows what other SVG properties in the CSS format. So it seems to work with the majority of properties but produces unexpected results with some. Ideally I'd like to be able to separate my styling from my structure whilst being cross browser friendly. **EDIT:** And what's worse is adding them as attributes like you suggested does nothing to fix the problem as shown in the last example above. In the case of `rx` and `ry` still nothing on IOS even as attributes in the HTML.

Comment: Things that in SVG 1.1 were attributes and in SVG 2 are CSS properties. Note that SVG 1.1 attributes do not support rem units

Comment: same problem here.